# Вывод данных json полученых ajax'ом

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

День добрый.
Есть небольшой скриптик который с помощью ajax-запроса получает данные посредством api.

Вот php-обработчик:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1251;');
if(isset($_GET['find'])) {
$val = $_GET['find'];
$clans = [];
$data = unserialize(file_get_contents('http://api.neverfate.ru/sostav.php?cl='.$val.''));
$clans[] = $data;
    echo serialize($clans);
//echo "<pre>".print_r($data,1)."</pre>";
    }
```

Результат полученный данным запросом (json) выглядит так:

```html
a:1:{
    i:0;
    a:20:{
  i:0;a:7:{s:5:"login";s:8:"testuser";s:5:"some_row";s:2:"some_text";s:8:"some_row1";s:1:"row1_text";s:10:"some_row2";s:0:"row2_test";s:5:"some_row3";s:1:"row3_text";s:4:"some_row4";s:10:"row4_text";s:3:"some_row5";s:10:"row5_text";}
  i:1;a:7:{s:5:"login";s:8:"testuser";s:5:"some_row";s:2:"some_text";s:8:"some_row1";s:1:"row1_text";s:10:"some_row2";s:0:"row2_test";s:5:"some_row3";s:1:"row3_text";s:4:"some_row4";s:10:"row4_text";s:3:"some_row5";s:10:"row5_text";}
    }
}
```

Сам ajax-запрос выглядит так:

```html
$(function (){

    $('#go').click(function() {
        var x = $('#search').val();

 $.ajax({
     url: 'api_js.php?find='+x,
     type: 'POST',
     success: function(info) {
            //TO DO...
     },
     error: function(statusCode) {
         $('#error').html('Error ocurred: ' + statusCode);
     }
 });

    });

});
```

Вот собственно много чего пробовал, но не получается вывести информацию.
Буду рад помощи.

Comment: json_encode/json_decode вам в помощь http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-encode.php

Comment: //TO DO... поменять на console.log(info)?

Comment: json_(en/de)code не помогает к сожалению.

Comment: Ну во-первых, `header('Content-Type: application/json');`. Во-вторых, `'dataType': 'json'` для настроек ajax. В-третьих, как было сказано выше `json_encode/json_decode`, т.к. сериализованный php массив это совсем не json.

Answer (score 1):

php

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
if(isset($_GET['find'])) {
    $val = $_GET['find'];
    $clans = [];
    $data = unserialize(file_get_contents('http://api.neverfate.ru/sostav.php?cl='.$val));
    $clans[] = $data;
    echo json_encode($clans);
}
```

js

```
...
$.ajax({
   url: 'api_js.php?find='+x,
   type: 'POST',
   success: function(info) {
       console.log(JSON.parse(info));
   },
   error: function(statusCode) {
       $('#error').html('Error ocurred: ' + statusCode);
   }
});
...
```